# Including Page Specific Assets

Tags: javascript, grails, asset-pipeline

Using the Grails asset-pipeline plugin, I'm trying to figure out the best way to include assets (javascript) on a page versus having them compiled into the application.js file. Currently, this is what I'm doing...

At the bottom of my layout file:

```
<g:set var="workflow" value="${pageProperty(name: 'meta.workflow')}"/>
<asset:javascript src="application.js"/>
<g:if test="${workflow == 'storeAdmin'}">
  <asset:javascript src="store/script.js"/>
</g:if>
```

In views/store/index.gsp header:

```
<meta name="workflow" content="storeAdmin" />
```

While this works, it feels like a hack. The reason I have to do it like this is because if I simply try and include the asset in the view itself, instead of the layout, it always gets rendered before the application.js, which means anything in that script that depends on global code will fail; code that requires jQuery for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use a convention for naming page specific javascript assets that reflects the name of the controller and action. Using these and the `<asset:assetPathExists>` tag I can just add the following into my layout:

```
<asset:assetPathExists src="${params?.controller ?: 'home'}_${params?.action ?: 'index'}.js">
  <asset:javascript src="${params?.controller ?: 'home'}_${params?.action ?: 'index'}.js" />
</asset:assetPathExists>
```

Comment: That's not bad. I'd still like to know if there is a way to just include the assets directly on the view instead of the layout file.

Comment: There isn't any reason why you can't do that. In fact, I do that all the time in my applications which use jquery and such. You may need to re-sequence how your assets get loaded in your layout (e.g. make sure you load your global asset manifest before `<g:layoutHead/>`.

Comment: I load application.js at the bottom of my layout, which allows for faster page loads. When including other javascript of views, they load before the end of the layout, so I can't get them to load after. I don't want to move my global manifest. :(

Comment: And there is the trade off. For my applications the measured difference between loading at the top vs bottom is roughly around 20-30ms in time to glass so I felt it was an acceptable approach.

Comment: Just seems like it should be something as simple as the ability to defer. I know you can defer pure script with a tag, but not files. Maybe I'll put in a feature request.